# iOS - App review process rules for disabled features

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I have an iPhone app (already in the App Store, free download) which requires the user to enter server and login credentials which are provided on a subscription basis.  The app has a built-in 'Demo Mode' for prospective customers to evaluate the app, and so far the Apple app review team have always used this mode to approve each version submitted.
The latest version which I'm about to submit has some new features which are not appropriate for use in the Demo Mode and are disabled in this mode.  No buttons are greyed out but an alert message is displayed to inform the user 'Not available in Demo Mode'.  My question is will this cause a problem with the Apple review team - will it be rejected because of disabled functionality?

Comment: You should provide the app review team with credentials they can use to evaluate the full app.  That's what I've always done.  There is a place in the app submit process to enter "review notes" where you can include this info.

Comment: So they could reject the app if they see any disabled functionality?  I'd rather only give out credentials if absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm surprised they haven't rejected it in the past.  You could be doing all sorts of things that violate their guidelines in the disabled parts of your app.

Comment: So far in all the versions submitted the Demo Mode includes ALL functionality.  It's only this new version about to be submitted where a couple of features are disabled.

Comment: ah, gotcha.  I don't know for certain if they will reject it (the rules are enforced somewhat arbitrarily) but to be safe I would give them credentials to test with.  You can always disable the test login after the app is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should give out the subscribed user credentials in the review notes of the application metadata you fill in while uploading the application, as they need to test the full application to complete their review process. Until the full app is reviewed don't even think of it getting approved and going live.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I showed a very similar message to your  'Not available in Demo Mode'.

Apple rejected the app, saying this would negatively impact the user experience!

I would try another approach - even if it's just in the documentation of the app on the info page.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Apple's review guidelines say that Trial or Demo apps will be rejected.

The opposite might be more acceptable.  Don't interrupt the user experience by saying that X is disabled or not available in the demo; but say that the app will be enhanced by the availability of X in your advertisement for customers to buy the full mode.